# Fetch Stackdriver logs in JSON from Google Cloud Stackdriver API with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm using Google's Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries for Python to programmatically retrieve log entries.
I want all the logs which you can see in Logs explorer section of GCP. Like this,

```
{
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
status: {0}
authenticationInfo: {
principalEmail: "abs@xyz.com"
}
requestMetadata: {
callerIp: "27.60.101.186"
callerSuppliedUserAgent: "pandas-0.24.2 gl-python/3.6.8 grpc/1.29.0 gax/1.14.2 gapic/1.17.0 gccl/1.17.0,gzip(gfe)"
}
serviceName: "bigquery.googleapis.com"
methodName: "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob"
..
}
```

I have written Python script to fetch the JSON but not getting the desired result. Here is my code.Kindly help what changes needs to be done to get all logs of a project or database.

```
    from google.cloud import logging
    from google.cloud.logging import DESCENDING
    import os
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="cred.json"
    
    logging_client = logging.Client()
    
    
    FILTER = 'resource.type="bigquery_dataset" resource.labels.dataset_id="data_reporting"'
    
    
    for entry in logging_client.list_entries(filter_=FILTER):  # API call
        print(entry)
```

Comment: You said you want to get "all" logs but it's not obvious which logs you're already getting and which are missed. Can you add this to the question?

Comment: Do you use the same filter in the GCP log explorer and in your code?

Comment: I want to view only particular fields like protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail or protoPayload.authorizationInfo.resourceAttributes.name without fetching the whole log. @Charnel